# Wireshark SNMP timeout display filter

Tags: wireshark, snmp

I'm using Wireshark 1.12.0 to analyze SNMP capture and **would like to find out the following**:

1). What is the Wireshark display filter to identify SNMP requests that take more than 100 seconds to respond to?

2). What is the Wireshark display filter to identify SNMP requests that do not have corresponding responses?

I have tried to examined Wireshark SNMP Display Filter Reference (https://www.wireshark.org/docs/dfref/s/snmp.html) without much success.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So, What's your question ?

Comment: Off-topic, SO is about programming questions.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear with the question. The questions I'm trying to find answers to are listed in the original post.